# How do i set up my job schedule in Azure batch account with different timedelta?

Tags: azure, azure-batch

I want my job can run at the first day of each mouth,but in azure batch account i only set up a fixed timedelta(Recurrence interval),how can i set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precise cron style jobs are not an option with Job Schedules. Controls are limited to the following [documented properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/batchservice/job-schedule/add#schedule). You will need to use a different trigger mechanism.

This is an active [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/a9fc6079-0c25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f07b8) item.